# How to download and save multiple files from a single online source?

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to use the riem package to download weather data from multiple airports.  I have code that currently downloads the weather for a single airport and saves it as station_METAR.csv where station is each individual city.  I am looking to have individual files for each city.  I have created another CSV file that I bring into the environment titled "stations" and was planning on using the values of this to repeat the process.

I need to iterate this download and save process for each individual city.

I don't necessarily have a specific problem as I'm new to coding in R and kind of struggling with how to tackle this loop.  Thanks in advance for the help!

````
x <- "KJFK"
start_date <- "2020-01-01"
end_date <- "2020-01-04"

#Download Station List
stations <- read_excel("~/Desktop/R WD/Reference Files/stations.xlsx", 
                       col_names = FALSE)

#View(stations)

#Download Data
METAR <- riem_measures(station = x, date_start = start_date,date_end = end_date)

#Write a CSV file with the City Name
write.table(METAR, file=paste(x, "_METAR", sep=""))```
````

Answer (score 0):

This lets you loop over each unique station and creates a filepath for each and then writes it to that path.

```
start_date <- "2020-01-01"
end_date <- "2020-01-04"

#Download Station List
stations <- read_excel("~/Desktop/R WD/Reference Files/stations.xlsx", 
                       col_names = FALSE)

# Select first column and turn it into a character vector. I assume other columns dont exist or arent important. Only use unique values, to avoid duplicates. 
stations = unique(as.character(stations[, 1]))

# loop over stations
for(station_name in stations) {
  
  #Download Data
  METAR <- riem_measures(station = station_name,
                         date_start = start_date,
                         date_end = end_date)
  
  # define filepath
  filepath = paste0(station_name, "_METAR.csv")
  
  #Write a CSV file with the City Name
  write.table(METAR, file=filepath)
  
}
```